# Is there a trigger which can help me to update a report table from a daily records table?I

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have two tables as shown below:  **Table_Report** needs to be updated from **Daily_Records** under these conditions:

- **Sold_Summary** column  needs to be updated by concatenating all **Sold_Item** where PIN is the same. Excluding special sold { Laptop, Smartphone, Tablets} which needs to be recorded in the **Special_sold** column.
- **Dest_Summary** column needs to be updated by concatenating all **Dest** when PIN is the same.
- **Special_sold** column needs to be updated the same way  when PIN is the same.
- **Special_sold** column only looks in the **Sold_Item** column if It finds any special sold { Laptop, Smartphone, Tablets} it records that under **Special_sold** when PIN is the same.

**Table1**: Daily_Records

| **ID | Date | PIN | Sold_Item | Dest** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-20 | 110 | Bag | Dawa |
| 2 | 2021-04-21 | 131 | Table | Harare |
| 3 | 2021-04-22 | 110 | Chair | Gondar |
| 4 | 2021-04-23 | 120 | Smartphone | Dawa |
| 5 | 2021-04-24 | 111 | Laptop | Adama |
| 6 | 2021-04-25 | 120 | Chair | Dawa |
| 7 | 2021-04-26 | 111 | Book | Harare |

**Table2:** Table_Report

| **ID | PIN | Sold_Summary | Dest_Summary | Special_sold** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | Bag, Chair | Dawa, Gondar | null |
| 2 | 111 | Book | Adama, Harare | Laptop |
| 3 | 120 | Chair | Dawa | Smartphone |
| 4 | 131 | Table | Harare | null |

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a trigger for this.  Just run a query:

```
select pin,
       group_concat(distinct case when sold_item not in ('Laptop', 'Smartphone', 'Tablet') then sold_item end) as sold_items,
       group_concat(distinct case when sold_item in ('Laptop', 'Smartphone', 'Tablet') then sold_item end) as sold_items_special,
       group_concat(distinct dest) as dest
from daily_records
group by pin;
```

You don't explain what `id` is.  You can add such a column as:

```
row_number() over (order by pin) as id
```

Comment: ID is an  index which is auto incremented.

Comment: @Laetitia . . . Then it will be set when you insert the data into the report table.

Comment: Exactly @Gordon